# Accessing a service on a Heroku app from another EC2 instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hi I am working on a project may be using RoR on Heroku that provides webservices to another EC2 instance running a C++ server. I understand that there is materials for accessing an EC2 instance from Heroku (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-services), but I have not seen one for the other way around.

I am wondering if there is a way to do a low-latency request from the EC2 C++ server to the Heroku service if both instances are hosted on the US-East region? (Something along the line that is mentioned in the above link, just in the opposite direction.)

I'm sure using normal HTTP request between the C++ instance and Heroku would work, but I was wondering if there's a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Heroku, but as they're running on EC2 connection both instances should be fairly simple. For minimal latency between each instances you should setup your C++-instance within the US-East region and use the internal DNS of the instances.

If you want to access your C++-instance from your Heroku instance you can use the [net-ssh gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/), which allows you to connect via ssh and do whatever you want directly on your C++-instance.

In some cases the processing on your C++-instance will take some time and your rails app will have to "wait" for results, so you may consider using a queue service to communicate between your instances. One example is Amazons SQS service: Just setup a queue and let the C++-instance post the information the rails app will need to the queue. You will have to write either a rake task that is started periodically by cron or you can write a daemon that runs continuously in the background to let the rails app collect the information from the queue.

Writing a rake task is easy, this should get you started: [rake, rake, rake your boat](http://nubyonrails.com/articles/rake-rake-rake-your-boat) and here is a Railscast that should give you some directions for writing a daemon: 
[#129 Custom Daemon](http://railscasts.com/episodes/129-custom-daemon).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I assume that this would work the same way when the C++ instance wants to make a call to the rails app on Heroku? However, as you said you're not familiar with Heroku, would you be able shed light on whether any sort of security configuration must be done to get that working?

Comment: If you want to SSH into your Heroku instance you have to open port 22. Or you can set up another SQS queue to send task / commands to your rails application (remember to write a background task for the rails application to listen to your commands from the SQS queue).